# Regex to match all files except one

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
http(s??)://abc.xyz.net.*/.*
```

Would like to modify the above regex to match all files except junk.js

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Providing examples could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Negative Lookahead.

```
^https?://(?!\S+(?:junk|abc|rst)\.js$)abc\.xyz\.net\S+$
```

Comment: what if I want to match all files except junk.js, abc.js and rst.js ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
^https?://abc\.xyz\.net[^/]*/(?!.*?\bjunk\.js\b).*$
```

- Better to warp regex in anchors `^` and `$`
- `(?!.*?\bjunk\.js\b)` is negative lookahead to avoid matching when `junk.js` comes after first `/`

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wZ3sM3/1)

**EDIT:** To exclude more than one file use:

```
^https?://abc\.xyz\.net[^/]*/(?!.*?\b(?:junk|abc|rst)\.js\b).*$
```

Comment: trying it on http://www.regexr.com/ and testing for http://abc.xyz.net/abc.js  provides no match.. I think it should provide a match

Comment: This will also reject `junk.jsb` and `jsjunk.js/more`. Is `(?!.*/junk\.js$))` at the very beginning an option?